# Uploading Photos to Facebook using Graph API in Rails3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to provide users of my application with ability to upload photos to their Facebook account. At present I'm using fb_graph gem to integrate Fb graph API.

Requirement is:

1. Before uploading the photo we need to check whether the user is logged in or not to facebook.
2. If user is logged in, we can directly upload the photo to his/her default album otherwise should show FB dialog to login and then upload process should be done.

I implemented the first point but blocked at second one. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Below is the sample code from fb_graph gem. Here the file is loading from a file system. But my scenario is file information should read from params. Because I'm using Heroku, as it is read only file system I can't upload the image directly and then FB.

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
album = me.albums.first
album.photo!(
  :access_token => ACCESS_TOKEN,
  :source => File.new('/Users/nov/Desktop/nov.gif', 'rb'), # 'rb' is needed only on windows
  :message => 'Hello, where is photo?'
)
```

Regards

Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Here is the question I asked (and solution I stumbled into) [Posting a photo to the Facebook Open Graph from Heroku, using RoR, FbGraph Gem, and S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877055/posting-a-photo-to-the-facebook-open-graph-from-heroku-using-ror-fbgraph-gem/8933971#8933971)

Comment: hello,i am using php to develop a photo posting app on facebook,using heroku,May i know whats the full path of temp file in heroku.since i need to pass the image url to facebook i need that full path.