# Posting a photo to the Facebook Open Graph from Heroku, using RoR, FbGraph Gem, and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, oauth, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to allow a user to share a photo on his Facebook wall. I use Paperclip to store all of my app's photos on S3. So in the below example @photo.image.url is the S3 url of an image that I want to post in some_album. Using the fb_graph gem this is relatively easy on localhost. In my controller I have:

```
    the_photo = open(@photo.image.url)
    some_album.photo!(
      :access_token => access_token,
      :source => the_photo
    )
```

the_photo's class on localhost is "Tempfile".

On heroku things get tricky. Using the same code two (seemingly related) things happen. First, the_photo is class type "stringIO". Second when FbGraph posts to Facebook I get the following error:

```
FbGraph::InvalidRequest (OAuthException :: (#324) Requires upload file):
```

Heres a few bullet points of facts that might also help:

- Heroku is a read only system, but apparently you *can* write to a Tempfile
- I am on Rails 3.1.0
- Ruby 1.9.2
- Heroku Stack Bamboo-Miri

Any help/thoughts/work arounds/questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this did the trick but this worked for me:

```
some_album.photo!(
  :access_token => access_token,
  :source => open(@photo.image.url)
)
```

as opposed to setting a variable photo_response = open(@photo.image.url).

Comment: It works because by saying open you are actually downloading the image from the url to your server before uploading it again.